# Java refuses to listen on IPv6 on Turnkey

Tags: networking, java, ipv6, turnkey

so i am using MineOS, a turnkey with preinstalled node.js webUI for deploying Minecraftservers. Now i want the server to be reachable via IPv6, because thats all i get from my ISP. But my server instance only ever listens on IPv4. How can i get the java minecraft server to listen on IPv6?

Some netstat -ntlp output, which is always the same, regardless of my server.properties in minecraft:

```
root@MinecraftServer /etc/default# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      493/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1194/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25565           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1446/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12319         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      590/shellinaboxd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12320           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      598/stunnel4
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12321           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      598/stunnel4
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      978/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      493/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      1026/node
```

I also tried using the -Djava.net.preferIPv6Adresses=true and -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true. Doesn't change a bit.
I changed the value for /proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only to 1.

Here my ip6tables -L:

```
root@MinecraftServer /etc/default# ip6tables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:25565
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:25566
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I am able to reach a server on a windows maschine over the internet via IPv6! I am also able to reach the webUI over IPv6 on the turnkey maschine.

What else am i missing? All help appretiated!

**SOLUTION:**

The forge modification for minecraft set java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true up to the version 1.12.2-14.23.1.2555, which ruins every IPv6 attempt. For that reason i am using 6tunnel now, which creates a port forward from IPv6 to IPv4. I am still not reachable from the outside on the minecraftserver, but IPv6 is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the forge modification i used with minecraft. Up to version
1.12.2-14.23.1.2555 it sets java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true. 6tunnel is a workaround, which does a port forward from IPv6 to IPv4.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got the property names wrong.  According to

- [Networking IPv6 User Guide for JDK/JRE 5.0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/index.html#using)

The property names are:

- `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` - note: `IPv4` not `IPv6`
- `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` - note: two `d` characters not one.

You also need to check that you are not affected by this bug: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-3776

Comment: I tested them all seperate, even the invalid ones. And my minecraft version is not affected by this. I found the culprit to be the forge modification, which just set java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true somewhere in their code. It was also patched but only in the newest versions, so i got unlucky.
I am using 6tunnel now and start it with a command at boot.